# ‘a slip of tongue’ or ‘a slip of the tongue’

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I see both in one book, and I feel it is weird why there were two phrases.

1. You made some slips of the tongue.
2. Are you sure that it was just a slip of tongue?

I guess the former is right.

Comment: You can easily use [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+slip+of+tongue%2Ca+slip+of+the+tongue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20slip%20of%20tongue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20slip%20of%20the%20tongue%3B%2Cc0) to check things like this if you're not sure.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I will try my best to do that, because I can not use it in China.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! The article ***is*** always included. I suppose that means you can't access [Google Books](https://books.google.com/) either. I'm not sure what your best alternatives are (apart from a VPN! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers VNP can not be used too. I live in a world blocked by the Great Wall.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Expressvpn can be used here, but it is too expensive that I can not bear.

Comment: You have my sympathy. Can you access, for example, "theguardian.com"? And does your browser support ***site-specific*** text searches? If I search The Guardian (a UK newspaper) for the text string "slip of the tongue" I get about 700 results, but there are just half-a-dozen for "slip of tongue".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can open this page, but what is the website about? Do you have a VPN?

Comment: I have access to a vpn, but I'm not using it right now. I use the Google Chrome browser (which I suppose you *can't* use), where I can precede my ("quotated") search term by **site:<websitename>** to find all occurrences of that string of words on that website. The Guardian is a quality newspaper (so long as you're not bothered by their political bias! :), so it's a good place to check which text sequences do or don't occur in English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Might you share that vpn with me?

Comment: No can do, sorry. Mine is a paid-for service (IpVanish), which I can only use on the computers in my own house, with my own user-id and password. I don't know anything about free vpns, but my guess is there would always be a catch - there's no such thing as a free lunch, in my experience!

Comment: ...but since you can access *this* site, you should be able to do a site-specific search on "english. stackexchange .com" - which for me returns 289 hits for *"**slip of the tongue**"* (but just 7 hits if I search again without the word ***the***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay, and I find that most vpns can not be used in China. I will search on that website.

Comment: It's often arbitrary whether we include an article or not in established collocations. The *cream of **the** crop* always gets it, but the *best of breed* pedigree dog who wins the prize never gets it. We do have article-less ***sleight of hand*** and *[by] **word of mouth***, which perhaps influences *some* of the relatively few instances of ***slip of tongue***, but it sounds a bit "whimsical, affected" to me.